# Somar as variáveis com o campo data iguais se possivel editando a coluna data

Tags: php, variáveis

Tenho as seguintes variáveis:

```
$v_data   = $row['DATA'];
$v_filial = $row['FILIAL'];
$v_chapa  = $row['CHAPA'];
$v_func   = $row['FUNCIONARIO'];
$v_dias   = $row['DIAS'];
$v_desc   = $row['DESCRICAO'];
```

Elas trazem isso:

```
DATA      FILIAL CHAPA  FUNCIONARIO    DIAS  DESCRICAO
10-04-2016  2    2311   JOAO DE SOUZA   7    TESTE
24-04-2016  2    2311   JOAO DE SOUZA   14   TESTE
08-05-2016  2    2311   JOAO DE SOUZA   14   TESTE
15-05-2016  2    2311   JOAO DE SOUZA   7    TESTE
05-06-2016  2    2311   JOAO DE SOUZA   21   TESTE
12-06-2016  2    2311   JOAO DE SOUZA   7    TESTE
```

O que preciso: 
 Onde as datas forem iguais somar a coluna dias e se possivel alterar a coluna data, exemplo:

```
DATA      FILIAL CHAPA  FUNCIONARIO    DIAS  DESCRICAO
10-04-2016  2    2311   JOAO DE SOUZA   7    TESTE
24-04-2016  2    2311   JOAO DE SOUZA   14   TESTE
```

Resultado esperado:

```
DATA      FILIAL CHAPA  FUNCIONARIO    DIAS  DESCRICAO  
  04         2    2311   JOAO DE SOUZA   21   TESTE
```

@Marllon Nasser, segue query:

```
SELECT 
       ifd_filial                  AS FILIAL,
       ifd_chapa                   AS CHAPA,
       ifd_nome                    AS NOME,
       DATE_FORMAT(ifd_dataa,'%m') AS MÊS,
       SUM(ifd_dias)               AS DIAS,
       ifd_desc                    AS DESCRICAO
       FROM 
            imp_folga_domingo 
            WHERE ifd_chapa = 2311
            GROUP BY ifd_dataa;
```

Comment: qual o banco? oracle?

Comment: Banco: SQL SERVER Mais gostaria de se possivel fazer em PHP por conta de outras condições que terei de fazer .

Comment: Bom, você tem que fazer um `group by` pelo mês da data... e fazer uma soma de `DIAS`. É isso que você precisa fazer..eu recomendo fazer pela query.. por php infelizmente eu não sei fazer isso. Mas a solução é essa.

Comment: @MarllonNasser trouxe para o MYSQL fiz a query mais não esta somando,poderia verificar se minha sintaxe esta correta ? Adicionei a mesma a pergunta .

Comment: @otaciojb somar se as datas forem igual ou se o mês da data for igual?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Mês

Comment: Vi o que estava errado pela pergunta de @Virgílio.

Comment: @otaciojb Faltou o `group by` na data... `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(ifd_dataa,'%m');`

Comment: @MarllonNasser isso mesmo, vlw..

Comment: Entendi !!! você quer uma solução `SQL` que o @MarllonNasser parece que já resolveu, o você quer um solução `PHP` ???

Comment: @VirgilioNovic para mim o PHP seria melhor,mais como preciso liberar fiz com a ajuda de vocês em sql mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue resultado final:

```
 SELECT 
       ifd_filial                  AS FILIAL,
       ifd_chapa                   AS CHAPA,
       ifd_nome                    AS NOME,
       DATE_FORMAT(ifd_dataa,'%m') AS MÊS,
       SUM(ifd_dias)               AS DIAS,
       ifd_desc                    AS DESCRICAO
       FROM 
            imp_folga_domingo 
            WHERE  ifd_chapa = 2311
                   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(ifd_dataa,'%m');
```